# Are there variables for current file or folder in the VS Code terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When in the terminal pane, I would like to reference the file or folder of the active editor tab via environment variable or PowerShell variable (preferred). Something like this:

`ii $vsActivePath`

or

`ii $vsActiveFile`

Is this possible?

Comment: What you are talking about is using `$pseditor` which is a variable offered in the Integrated Terminal for PS extension. Right now not much is available, a [related SO question on same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265842/visual-studio-code-psise-equivalent).

Comment: The SO question you linked lead me to [PowerShellEditorServices](http://brandonpadgett.com/powershell/Getting-Started-With-Editor-Commands/). Some work is needed as there is no module form yet but this is promising.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but you can get access to various variables in vs code such as:

```
${workspaceRoot} the path of the folder opened in VS Code
${workspaceRootFolderName} the name of the folder opened in VS Code without any slashes (/)
${file} the current opened file
```

[Full details can be found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution)

Comment: How to access that in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

They have added some new variables and it contains `${fileDirname}` which is the path to the directory where your current `${file}` is. 
The documentation seems to be a bit misleading here.

Those are the current available options:

```
${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code
${workspaceFolderBasename} - the name of the folder opened in VS Code without any slashes (/)
${file} - the current opened file
${relativeFile} - the current opened file relative to workspaceFolder
${fileBasename} - the current opened file's basename
${fileBasenameNoExtension} - the current opened file's basename with no file extension
${fileDirname} - the current opened file's dirname
${fileExtname} - the current opened file's extension
${cwd} - the task runner's current working directory on startup
${lineNumber} - the current selected line number in the active file
```

Comment: These are for variable substitution in conf files, but they do not appear to be available in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've found is this: You can set up a keybinding which sends text to the terminal.

In keybindings.json, add an entry like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "${relativeFile}" },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

As you can see, variable substitution works, so you can insert the file, relative file, path, etc. (as described in [Sn0wfreeze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47653607/243516))

Also note, I used a "when" clause in my example in order to politely override an existing shortcut only when the terminal is the active focus. This is optional.

I think this is distinctly less good than having a variable to type in-line, but it's been good enough for my day-to-day. You could probably get fancy with sequenced shortcuts to give lots of options, such as:

```
ctrl+f, ctrl+f => ${file}
ctrl+f, ctrl+r => ${relativeFile}
ctrl+f, ctrl+d => ${fileDirname}
etc.
```

[Original source on visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Extensions.EditorObject` from [PowerShellEditorServices](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices) provided by the [PowerShell Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell):

```
$psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path
```

> **Note:** The `$psEditor` object is only available in the VSC Terminal Pane when using the PowerShell Extension prompt, which may not be the one that opens by default. It activates automatically when you open a PowerShell file, or when using the the "PowerShell: Show Extension Terminal" command from the VSC Command Palette.