# Visual Studio Code $psise equivalent

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to replicate the $psISE functionality in VSCode, at least as far as discovering the filename of the open, active file in the editor.

As background:

I'm trying to migrate into using VSCode for powershell editing instead of the ISE since VSCode is the future. We're having issues with migrating some workflows (specifically signing scripts).  In the ISE, I have created a function that uses the `$psise.currentfile.fullpath` so that we can easily sign the file that's open in the ISE.  I'd like to recreate this for vscode, but I'm not finding any way to determine what the open file is.  We tend to run this interactively (i.e. we're testing in the ISE, get it to where we want to test on another box, and sign it by just typing `Set-CoSAuthenticodeSignature`, which is a custom function that wraps `set-authenticodesignature` but has defaults set and automatically finds the file, if we don't specify), so we don't want to have to type the path name all the time, especially since we don't have to now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's not implemented yet (the $psise). You can file an issue on the [vscode-powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell) Project for VSCode. A [similar one](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/773) has already been filed.

At least you might use something like
`$context = [Microsoft.Powershell.EditorServices.Extensions.EditorContext]$psEditor.GetEditorContext()`

Then you can access the current file... 
`$context.CurrentFile.`

See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQbUxuA0u8k) for an introduction...

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you! to get the path of the file it's actually `$context.CurrentFile.Path`.  Your solution gets me more info than I asked so that's awesome!  THANKS!

Comment: As a single command: `$psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path` returns the current file's full path.

Comment: The VSCode PowerShell's extension `$psEditor` variable is the _analog_ of the ISE's `$psISE` variable (the name `$psISE` wouldn't be appropriate in VSCode).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ScriptPath=''
if($ScriptPath -eq '' -and $MyInvocation.MyCommand.CommandType -eq 'ExternalScript'){$ScriptPath = (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source                  -Parent)} # Running from File
if($ScriptPath -eq '' -and (Test-Path variable:psISE)) {                             $ScriptPath = (Split-Path -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath                     -Parent)} # Running from ISE
if($ScriptPath -eq '' -and (Test-Path variable:psEditor)) {                          $ScriptPath = (Split-Path -Path $psEditor.GetEditorContext().CurrentFile.Path   -Parent)} # Running from Visual Studio Code
```

Comment: Improve your answer with supporting information for better understanding.