# How can I customize powershell when running inside of the VSCode integrated terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I would like to include a few Powershell customizations that only occur when running inside of VSCode.

When inside of ISE or Package Management Console (inside Visual Studio), I can use the value of `$host.name` to switch behavior or include specific code in the "host specific" powershell profile (e.g. `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`).

Powershell inside of VSCode appears identical to Powershell running in a regular console so most of these options aren't available.  Is there anyway to workaround this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode sets the `TERM_PROGRAM` environment variable to `vscode` in its integrated terminal, so you can use the following test, which works whether or not the PowerShell extension is installed:

```
$runningInVsCode = $env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq 'vscode'
```

Answer (score 4):

See also [Visual Studio Code $psise equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265842/visual-studio-code-psise-equivalent)

You may check for $psISE, and if it does not exist, try `$context = [Microsoft.Powershell.EditorServices.Extensions.EditorContext]$psEditor.GetEditorContext()` but be aware, this will throw in ISE.

I use this snippet in a lot of my scripts, so I can always reference "$root".

```
# Makes debugging from ISE easier.
if ($PSScriptRoot -eq "")
{
    if ($psISE)
    {
        $root = Split-Path -Parent $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
    }
    else
    {
        $context = $psEditor.GetEditorContext()
        $root = Split-Path -Parent $context.CurrentFile.Path
    }
}
else
{
    $root = $PSScriptRoot
}
```

Comment: Very happy to see $psEditor.   I didn't know that was a thing before.  I picked the other answer because I'm not actually editing Powershell code, just using the terminal, so I don't want to depend on having the extension installed.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if VSCode-specific environment variables exist:

```
if((Test-Path env:\VSCODE_PID) -or ($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq 'vscode')){
  # Running from Vistual Studio Code
}
```

Comment: Simple, works without any extensions and should work all the time!  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this environment variable appears to be no longer defined as of (at least) VSCode v1.30.2. In fact, on macOS and Linux no `VSCODE*` environment variables appear to be defined at all. On Windows I only see `VSCODE_CWD`.

Comment: @mklement0 is correct, these variables don't seem to be set anymore, so I'm un-marking this answer as correct. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check you have VSCode context. The simplest way is to test current VSCode process ID.

```
if ($Env:VSCODE_PID) {  }
```

And the ISE has own profile (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this environment variable appears to be no longer defined as of (at least) VSCode v1.30.2. In fact, on macOS and Linux no `VSCODE*` environment variables appear to be defined at all. On Windows I only see `VSCODE_CWD`.