# PowerShell Move Script - Dynamic Directory

Tags: powershell

I am creating a PowerShell Move Script that will dynamically create directories based on the filename and then move the files according to their name. Every aspect of this script works except for the default directory path. Any idea how I could automatically change it to the directory of the Script Location. I've tried:
`cd $PSScriptroot` with no luck

**Here is my Helper File, to create the files. In our real environment the files would already be generated:**
    `cd $PSScriptroot
    New-Item -Path ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + '20180101' + '.txt') -ItemType file
    New-Item -Path ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + '20180102' + '.txt') -ItemType file
    New-Item -Path ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + '20180103' + '.txt') -ItemType file
    New-Item -Path ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + '20180104' + '.txt') -ItemType file
    ...
    New-Item -Path ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + '20181231' + '.txt') -ItemType file`

**Here is the script:**

```
`cd $PSScriptroot
$FileNameArray = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt"
$FileNameArray = $FileNameArray -replace "....$"
$FileNameArray = $FileNameArray.Substring(3)
Foreach ($f in $FileNameArray)
{
    #Year
    $Year = $f -replace "....$"
    $FilePathY = "$PSScriptroot\$Year" 
    if (Test-Path $FilePathYM ){
    }
    else {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($FilePathY)}
    #Month
    $Month = $f.Substring(4) -replace "..$"
    $FilePathYM = "$PSScriptroot\$Year\$Month"
     if (Test-Path $FilePathYM ){
    }
    else {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($FilePathYM)}
    #Days
    $Day = $f.Substring(6)
    $FilePathYMD = $PSScriptroot +'\'+ $Year +'\'+ $Month +'\'+ $Day
     if (Test-Path $FilePathYMD){
    }
    else {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($FilePathYMD)}
}
Foreach($file in $FileNameArray)
{
        $Year = $file -replace "....$"
        $Month = $file.Substring(4) -replace "..$"
        $Day = $file.Substring(6)`

        Move-Item ($PSScriptroot + '\59_' + $file + '.txt' ) ($PSScriptroot + '\' + $Year + '\' + $Month + '\' + $Day)
}`
```

Comment: What does "every aspect of this script works except for the default directory path" mean? What happens? (Remember: Nobody can see your screen!)

Comment: The filepath is set to that of the users default directory. So the files will typically move to the C:\ drive or whichever location that user sets as their default directory.

Comment: But the files are moved to the correct folder as planned and the folders are created without error.

Comment: What does "filepath is set to that of the users default directory" mean? What user? What directory? There seems to be large chunks of information missing from your question. Sorry that I'm not able to help.

Comment: If you want the current location that the script is running in `Get-Location` might be what you are looking for

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511874/how-can-i-customize-powershell-when-running-inside-of-the-vscode-integrated-term. $PSScriptroot is not always available.

Comment: jrdider I think your onto something with Get-Location. However it will change to the current working directory not necessarily the Scripts directory. How would I use Get-Location to call the scripts location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from comments I understand that the Script runs fine without error and that you want to the path that points to the Script location

> Any idea how I could automatically change it to the directory of the Script Location. I've tried: cd $PSScriptroot with no luck

**Try this**: (Tested: It points to the Directory where the script resides)

```
$rootPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
echo "Path is: $rootPath"
```

`$PSScriptRoot` is introduced in PowerShell **version 3**

**TIP**: Try `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` to know the Version.