# System.IO.File Current Directory Use Only TXT File

Tags: powershell

I have a folder location

```
Z:\MyFolder\Hours
```

And in this folder, I have two files, a PowerShell script and a text (txt) file; I will only ever have these two files in this folder, but the text file name changes every week. My PowerShell script is below and works, but what I would like it to do it to get the current directory it is stored (or was opened) from, open the only txt file in the directory, and run the script on it. Currently, the opening and saving of the txt file is hard-coded, and I would like to use this same script on some files that names change daily. I appreciate anyone's help!

```
    $r = @{
    "Mon" = "Monday";
    "Tue" = "Tuesday";
    "Wed" = "Wednesday";
    "Thu" = "Thursday";
    "Fri" = "Friday";
    "Sat" = "Saturday";
    "Sun" = "Sunday"
}


$regexes = $r.keys | foreach {[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Escape($_)}
$regex = [regex]($regexes -join '|')

$callback = { $r[$args[0].Value] }

$file = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("Z:\MyFolder\Hours\file.txt")
$file = $regex.Replace($file, $callback)
Set-Content -Path Z:\MyFolder\Hours\file.txt -Value $file
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer for how to get directory from which script is executing.
[How can I customize powershell when running inside of the VSCode integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511874/how-can-i-customize-powershell-when-running-inside-of-the-vscode-integrated-term/48512008#48512008)

For getting the only (or first) txt file in a directory do something like:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Z:\MyFolder\Hours' -Filter *.txt | Select -First 1 | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

This should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out my problem with the solution shown below:

```
(Get-Content *.txt) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'Mon\b', 'Monday' `
       -replace 'Tue\b', 'Tuesday' `
       -replace 'Wed\b', 'Wednesday' `
       -replace 'Thu\b', 'Thursday' `
       -replace 'Fri\b', 'Friday' `
       -replace 'Sat\b', 'Saturday' `
       -replace 'Sun\b', 'Sunday'
    } | Set-Content *.txt
```

This allows for the PowerShell script to open in the current directory, open the only text (txt) file within that directory, make the replacements, and save the file.

Comment: I don't think this is a viable solution, each `Monday` would be expanded to `MonMonday` etc. append a `\b` to the short weekday names to limit to word boundaries.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I hadn't experienced this as when my script is run, the file will only ever contain the short names, and will never run on the same file twice. I did test your theory, as despite the outcome being slightly different, it did produce an issue. I'm not sure that I would've ever encountered this, but for the sake of it being foolproof, I made the edit as you suggested. Thank you, again.