# MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path in ISE vs regular PS

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an old script that invokes itself with some extra params in a certain situation. This works if run through a regular powershell window

```
$spath = $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$FilePathWithQuotes = '"{0}"' -f $spath 
powershell -file $FilePathWithQuotes -NestedCall @ExtraArgs
```

but if it's run through the ISE I get this error.

> powershell : Add-Type : Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target.
>   Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path  At D:\Deploy\File
>   Deploy.ps1:39 char:5
>   +     powershell -file $FilePathWithQuotes -NestedCall @ExtraArgs
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Add-Type : Cann...nnot find path :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I added the second line to make sure the spaces weren't the issue but it still fails in the ISE.
 Thoughts? Im on ps 5.1

Comment: see this answer for console/ise/vscode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511874/how-can-i-customize-powershell-when-running-inside-of-the-vscode-integrated-term/48512008#48512008

Comment: `$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` should work in the ISE too (assuming the tab's content has been saved to a script file). As an aside, there's no need to wrap the file path in embedded double quotes (I'm surprised that even works). Note how the error relates to `Add-Type`, so you'll need to show that call for further diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, check for `$PSISE`, and use that if possible.

```
$spath = If($PSISE){$psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath}else{$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path}
$FilePathWithQuotes = '"{0}"' -f $spath 
powershell -file $FilePathWithQuotes -NestedCall @ExtraArgs
```

Comment: `$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` should work in the ISE too (assuming the tab's content has been saved to a script file), so there's no need for the `if` statement (at least in PSv5.1). As an aside, it's worth pointing out that there's no need to wrap the file path in embedded double quotes (I'm surprised that even works)