# Is it possible to get the full file name of the file you have open/are viewing in VS Code via the integrated Terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

In the VS Code terminal, is there a command that will give you the name of the file that you currently have open? e.g. just the file name `IndexController.php`?

I frequently run a test command in my terminal `make test-watch /long/path/to/file.php` and I need to right click on the file name and select "copy relative path" to get that path, which I then have to paste in.

It would save me a little bit of hassle if I could add a `make test-watch-here` that just read from the open file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.19.0

With the command `extension.commandvariable.inTerminal` you can type the result of a command in the terminal.

The extension contains also a command to transform a string with [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) to there value.

An example for your case:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "${relativeFile}" }
    }
  }
```

The key combo works in the editor and the terminal.

See the doc of the extension to see what you can do more with the `transform` command (like find/replace with regexp)

Comment: This should really be edited to use the non-extension `sendSequence` command with `{file}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592640/are-there-variables-for-current-file-or-folder-in-the-vs-code-terminal/67731345#67731345